# The control Type is hidden - Coded Ui

Tags: visual-studio, coded-ui-tests

While trying to automate an web application using Coded UI, I faced the following issue :-
**"Failed to perform Action on hidden control exception: Cannot perform 'Set property of text with value "Muj*****" on the hidden control'.**

Version used:-
**Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2012//
Version:11.0.50727.1**

**Microsoft .NET Framework
Version:4.5.50709**

**IE Version used:11.0**

This is a internet banking application. Once I launch the browser with the application URL, I will be able to view the page in two languages. One in Arabic (default) and there is a Hyperlink to change the preferred language to English. So once I click on the hyper link and try to pass the Username and password to the respective fields, I get the above mentioned error. But without changing the language to English, the credentials are passed successfully. Again once I enter into the next page, I face the above mentioned issue to control the objects.

I assume that once we navigate from one page to the other, we face this issue.

Got to know this could be due to One Security update in IE (KB2870699). But this security update is not installed in my PC. Instead (KB3003057) is installed. I am not sure if this could be a reason for this issue. Just mentioning this here.

Kindly provide me a solution on how can I proceed.

Comment: it would be very helpful to know more about the webpage your working with, like the rendered html from the page, is the text box actually available (not hidden, disabled in any way). and details of validation the text box performs

Comment: @MichaelJamesRieger: I have edited the query. Please check into this and let me know of any known solutions.